# while loop inserts only the last row using checkbox php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Here is my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $currency  =  $_POST['currency'];
    $amount    =  $_POST['amount'];
    $integer   =  0;
    //Loop using while, check the count
    while(count($currency) > $integer) {

        $currencyArray         = array(
                                        'currency'      =>  $currency[$integer],
                                        'amount'            =>  $amount[$integer]
                                        );

        //Insert statement constructed to array
        //..... insert into        
        //Stop loop when reach to the limit
        $integer = $integer + 1;
    }
}
?>

<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type="checkbox" class="currency" name="currency[]" value="USD">USD
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value = "">

<input type="checkbox" class="currency" name="currency[]" value="EUR">EUR
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value = "">

<input type="checkbox" class="currency" name="currency[]" value="JPY">JPY
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value = "">

<input type="checkbox" class="currency" name="currency[]" value="PHP">PHP
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value = "">


<input type = "submit" name = "submit">

</form>
```

Note: with **parenthesis ()** is the amount

I have a situation if I input the currency sequentially like I select USD and enter an amount (**50**) and next is EUR (**2**) it saves two records, saves the amount correctly on the field but if I select EUR (**50**) and JPY (**500**) it saves two records but the first record saves the amount into **zero** the second record saves **50**. the first record must be **50** and second must be **500**. Is there anything i missing?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $currency  =  $_POST['currency'];
    $amount    =  array();
    $integer   =  0;

    foreach($_POST['amount'] as $amount_value) {
       if($amount_value != '')    { 
         $amount[]   =  $amount_value;
       }
    }
    //Loop using while, check the count
    while(count($currency) > $integer) {

        $currencyArray         = array(
                                        'currency'      =>  $currency[$integer],
                                        'amount'            =>  $amount[$integer]
                                        );

        //Insert statement constructed to array
        //..... insert into        
        //Stop loop when reach to the limit
        $integer = $integer + 1;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT FOR RESULT OF ARRAY**

For the amount: 
Array ( [0] => [1] => 25 [2] => [3] => 50 [4] => [5] => 25 [6] => 50 )

For the currency:
Array ( [0] => EUR [1] => JPY )

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, if you print out `$amount`, you will see something like:

```
$amount[0] equals ""
$amount[1] equals "50"
$amount[2] equals "500"
$amount[3] equals ""
```

while your `$currency[0]` equals to 'EUR' and `$currency[1]` equals to 'JPY', it's inconsistent with what you think.

You need to manually remove those empty value from `$amount` before execute your while-loop

**Edit:** update with solution, use `array_filter()` to remove empty value in $amount array

```
$amount = array_filter($amount);
```

[array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php): "If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed."

Comment: what should i do to amount $amount[0] equals to 50 and $amount[1] equals to 500?

Comment: Just updated my answer with solution, use that array_filter() line before your while(count($currency) > $integer)

Comment: sorry not working. put $amount = array_filter($_POST['amount'])

Comment: once you remove empty value in $amount, then your program should function normally. no need to do any other things for your $currency array.

Answer (score 0):

That's why because amount[] is always set, because no value is also a value in a text field!
Currency on the other side is only set if the checkbox is selected.

So `count($amount)` is always 4 whereas `count($currency)` depends on the selected checkboxes.

If you now select 50 EUR and 100 JPY and loop through the array then the follow will happen:

`$amount[0] = ""`, because the first amount field is empty

`$currency[0] = "EUR"`, because USD is ignored

`$amount[1] = "50"`, because 50 is in the next field, which is EUR

`$currency[1] = "JPY"`, because the next checkbox is JPY

Comment: You could try it with: $amount = array(); foreach($_POST['amount'] as $amount_value) { if($amount_value != "") $amount[] = $amount_value; } instead of $amount = $_POST['amount'];

Comment: how about the currency?

Comment: Currency should only be set if the checkbox is selected. Does it work so?

Comment: And when you try to make the same with currency? (foreach...)

Comment: the currency saves with no problem.

Comment: Please edit your post with the return values of print_r($currency) and print_r($amount) before your while loop

Comment: You made a mistake. You forgot the if() I posted in my comment above and you should use $amount[$integer] at your array.

Comment: In your post above you have to change $amount to $amount[$integer] near your currencyArray.

Comment: i tried it but not working. first issue result. i also edited my post

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the return values of print_r($amount) and print_r($currency). Put these between your while loop and foreach loop.

Comment: i edited the post with the results of print_r($amount) and print_r($currency)

Comment: That's strange. What do you insert into the fields? You've got 4 amount fields, correct? Did you insert 25 in the second and 50 in the third field? You can also try using if(!empty($amount_value)) instead of if($amount_value != '') but then 0 will be empty, too.

Comment: i tried if(!empty($amount_value)) not working either. what can be the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42414/discussion-between-marcel-balzer-and-shudmeyer)